# Why are different endpoints in the same API returning different date formats?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have two different API endpoints.  Both controllers inherit `ApiController`.  Both return a single object, each of which has a field of type `DateTime`.

**API 1:**

```
[Route("OtherThings/{otherThingId:guid}/FirstThing", Name = "GetFirstThing")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Response1))]
public IHttpActionResult GetFirstThing(Guid otherThingId, [FromUri] DateTime? modifiedDate = null)
{
    var things = GetThings(otherThingId, modifiedDate);
    if (!things.Any())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(new Response1(things.First()));
}
```

where Response1 is defined as:

```
public class ReadingProgressResponse
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    // and other properties
}
```

sample response:

```
{
    "dateTime": "2016-09-28T14:30:26"
}
```

**API 2**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{someId:guid}", Name = "SomeName")]
[ResponseType(typeof (Response2))]
public IHttpActionResult GetResponse2(Guid someId)
{
    var data = GetSomeData(someId);

    return Ok(new Response2(data));
}
```

where `Response2` is defined as:

```
public class ScreenSessionResponse
{
    public DateTime ExpirationTime { get; set; }
    // and other fields
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "expirationTime": "2016-09-28T14:48:09Z"
}
```

Notice that API 1 does not have a "Z" at the end of the date, but API 2 does.

Why?  Do I have any control over how the response gets formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have control on how dates are formatted.

Try this code in the OnStart method of your global.asax:

```
// Convert all dates to UTC
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

For more info, have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_dates)